How is this question opinion based?
B"H
Why do some frum Jews go to college, even though the Lubavitcher Rebbe writes that it's completely forbidden for all Jews forever?
This question is clearly NOT opinion based because it is only asking for any official published justification for college from any rav or rabbi in response to the very specific points mentioned in the sources. Nothing opinionated about it.

On the first page in our Help Center, "What types of questions should I avoid asking?", one of the examples listed is "your question is just a rant in disguise: '______ [stinks], am I right?'" The line between this form of question and one that constructively provides background regarding a practice or concept and then asks for information about sources that discuss it is naturally a blurry one, as the "Am I right?" punchline is facially a request for information. The judgement call to make is whether the question is more likely to inspire informative answer posts or argumentative back-and-forth.
In this case, as expressed by multiple comments, voting on the post, and close votes, the sense of the community appears to be that this post is on the less constructive side of the line.
When a post receives such criticism, the best available tactic for reversing the sense of the community is to edit the post to take the criticism into account. Arguing in and around the post that it is ideal in its current form tends to be much less likely to succeed.
Based on the comments and on my reading of the post, my suggestion would be to rewrite the post to heavily emphasize the request for information and de-emphasize the promotion of a particular point-of-view. Here's a possible outline:

The issue of whether to go to college can be a religiously fraught one.
Examples of problems
I'm aware of one gadol of the 20th Century, the Lubavitcher Rebbe, who wrote powerfully against the practice (citations).
What responsa [in a specific era, if desired] have been written in favor?

